# Transfer cookies & session from CURL to header location

Tags: php, curl, cookies

I have a curl request that is sending data to an external source. After post is completed, i extract the destination URL and redirect it through a header("Location: $url");.

**Problem**: While it does redirect, the data is no longer present. The cookie or the session is not being passed through with the header location.

What would be the best way of transferring the header details to the Header location?

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'postdata=' . urlencode(xmlData()));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');

// Download the given URL, and return output
$output = curl_exec($ch);

// Cookie Match
preg_match_all('/^Set-Cookie:\s*([^\r\n]*)/mi', $output, $ms);
// print_r($result);
$cookies = array();
foreach ($ms[1] as $m) {
    list($name, $value) = explode('=', $m, 2);
    $cookies[$name] = $value;
}
print_r($cookies);

$redirect = curl_getinfo($ch)['redirect_url'];

header('HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect');
header("Location: $redirect");

//Close Match
curl_close($ch);
```

I tried the cookie preg match all but it brings back an empty array.

Comment: The browser and the curl session are in affect two separate entities, the cookie will not be sent unless you specify that as a header I would guess. Try adding `header("Set-Cookie: $cookiedata");` etc