# How to connecting to the remote site with CURL and header location

Tags: php, curl, cookies, session-cookies

I am logging from site A through CURL on site B, I get the cookies from the connection and write to file called cookie.txt.

But when I pass the cookie data to do the final header redirection ('Location: http://examplesiteb.com'), it returns disconnected.

The code I am using for connection is the same as in this other post, but with my modifications following the @ramrider user's suggestion that I suggested passing the cookies in the header, but I'm not sure how this should be done.

[Transfer cookies & session from CURL to header location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33463793/transfer-cookies-session-from-curl-to-header-location/48235350#48235350)

```
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 10);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');

  // Download the given URL, and return output
  $output = curl_exec($ch);

  // Cookie Match
  preg_match_all('/^Set-Cookie:\s*([^\r\n]*)/mi', $output, $ms);

  $cookies = array();
  foreach ($ms[1] as $m) {
    list($name, $value) = explode('=', $m, 2);
    $cookies[$name] = $value;

    header('Set-Cookie: '.rawurlencode($name).'='.rawurlencode($value));
  }

  //print_r($cookies);

  $redirect = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);

  header("Location: $redirect");

  //Close Match
  curl_close($ch);
```

The redirect happens but does not keep logged in.

Below the example cookie file

```
# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# http://curl.haxx.se/docs/http-cookies.html
# This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.

#HttpOnly_example.com   FALSE   /   FALSE   0   ASP.NET_SessionId   10gtonkebkteuazx24sajlh2
#HttpOnly_example.com   FALSE   /   TRUE    1515800212  DTE 898EC9C0EF0BA3985E402046547931EAA55808E14A2DE469F11F6F6C0CF9A28871C8704BE794885CDF7D3EE1E8B06698166F86C184C5B53FE61FA53CA13682C562E17BCB7B2FA16D7A7180E6EA973735
```

The users @martijn-pieters and @waqas-bukhary if they can help I thank you, because you deleted my answer in the other post, and I was completing with additional information for others that I can not find a solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are tied to the domain that sends them.  You cannot set cookies for a different domain.

If "Site B" (where you are using cURL to log in to "Site A") is `example.com`, and "Site A" is `not-example.com`, the cookies set by `Set-Cookie` are for `example.com` and will not apply to `not-example.com`.

There is no mechanism to set cookies for a domain other than your own.

See [RFC 6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265) Section 5.3 (Storage Model) Part 6:

> If the domain-attribute is non-empty:
>
> - If the canonicalized request-host does not domain-match the domain-attribute:
> - - Ignore the cookie entirely and abort these steps.

This effectively says that a browser must ignore a cookie if site A attempts to set a cookie for site B.